# XeLatex otf font won't load

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I am very inexperienced with LaTeX. I have a tex file that has worked for a long time, then stopped without any changes to the file.

We purchased NeueHaasGrotDisp font.  I have the fonts in OTF format.

I am getting the following error:

```
(C:\myPath\Program\Binaries\miktex\tex\xelatex\fontspec\fontspec.cfg))Running miktex-makemf.exe...
miktex-makemf: The NeueHaasGrotDisp-55Roman source file could not be found.

Running hbf2gf.exe...
hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.3)

Couldn't find `NeueHaasGrotDisp-55Rom.cfg'

miktex-maketfm: No creation rule for font NeueHaasGrotDisp-55Roman.

! Font \zf@basefont=NeueHaasGrotDisp-55Roman at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric(TFM) file or installed font not found.
\zf@fontspec ...ntname \zf@suffix " at \f@size pt 
                                              \unless \ifzf@icu \zf@set@...
l.151 {NeueHaasGrotDisp}
```

My code:

```
...
\usepackage{fontspec}

...
%Regular Font
\newfontfamily\nhg [
  Path = {/Program Files (x86)/program/fonts/},
  BoldFont = *-75Bold,
  UprightFont = *-55Roman,
  ItalicFont = *-36ThinItalic,
  Extension = .otf
]

{NeueHaasGrotDisp}
%Light Font
\newfontfamily\nhgl [
  Path = {/Program Files (x86)/program/fonts/}, 
  BoldFont = *-75Bold,
  UprightFont = *-45Light,
  Extension = .otf
]
{NeueHaasGrotDisp}
```

At `/Program Files (x86)/program/fonts/` I have the following files:

- NeueHaasGrotDisp-36ThinItalic.otf
- NeueHaasGrotDisp-45Light.otf
- NeueHaasGrotDisp-55Roman.otf
- NeueHaasGrotDisp-75Bold.otf

Would this happen if our font license expired?  Is this checked when the font is loaded?

Comment: Are you missing `Extension = .otf` or similar?

Comment: my `.tex` file doesn't have that code anywhere.  Where would I put that?

Comment: As one of the keys to `\newfontfamily`.

Comment: I updated my code by including the `Extension = .otf` as a key to newfontfamily and I got all the same errors.

Comment: Does windows allow paths with that format? I would have assumed you'd need to have `Path={C:/Program Files/program/fonts/}`. Also, it looks like you're using an *extremely* old version of `fontspec`. I recommend updating to the latest version of MiKTeX if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Will_Robertson pointed out, I had an old version of fontspec installed.  I actually had multiple versions of fontspec installed in different folders in miktex.  Miktex was finding the older version and using it.  Once I deleted the old version, it started working.

Answer (score 2):

Your path needs to be surrounded by braces `{}`. I also separate the ending comma-delimiters with a space.

Here is how I would do it.

I used:

1. Folder called **Fonts** inside of base directory (where your font files are located)
2. MinionPro*.otf (grabs all variants, assuming your file name scheme is fontname-type.otf where -type represents: -Bold, -Italic, -Regular, etc.)

*(I have an extra file for semibold that I did not load with fontspec. I usually overcome this limitation by creating another font family or by replacing the bold font depending on the situation.)*

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\yourcustomnameforthisfont[%
    Path = {Fonts/} ,
    Extension = .otf ,
    UprightFont = *-Regular ,
    ItalicFont = *-It ,
    BoldFont = *-Bold ,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldIt
    ]{MinionPro}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
{\yourcustomnameforthisfont\lipsum}
\end{document}
```

## Output

(Note that I am missing the `lipsum` package in the screenshot and the `\yourcustomnameforthisfont`. The screenshot is to show the relationship between the `\newfontfamily` code and the files.)
[image]

Comment: I made those changes and the result is the same.  Also note that I have the OTF files outside of Miktex.  They are just in a random place on the computer (but my path is right).  that shouldn't be a factor right?  I also read something about a cache.  Might the font be missing from the cache?