# Error loading .otf font in xelatex

Tags: fonts, xetex

I'm certain this must be a duplicate as there are lots of very similar questions, but none of the answers I can find work for me.

I have a set of `.otf` font files (one each for the regular, italic, bold and bold italic versions) which I want to use as the default font in a XeLaTeX document.  I've tried lots of ways of loading them, but here's a concrete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{HelveticaNeueLTPro}[
  Path = /home/richard/,
  UprightFont = *-Roman,
  BoldFont = *-Bd,
  ItalicFont = *-It,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BdIt,
  Extension = .otf]

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

At the moment, this `test.tex` file plus the four `.otf` files are in my home directory (`/home/richard/`):

```
richard@fannich:~$ ls -l *.otf *.tex
-rw-r--r-- 1 richard richard 21608 Mar 14 21:44 HelveticaNeueLTPro-BdIt.otf
-rw-r--r-- 1 richard richard 22776 Mar 14 21:44 HelveticaNeueLTPro-Bd.otf
-rw-r--r-- 1 richard richard 17404 Mar 14 21:44 HelveticaNeueLTPro-It.otf
-rw-r--r-- 1 richard richard 26936 Mar 14 21:44 HelveticaNeueLTPro-Roman.otf
-rw-r--r-- 1 richard richard   290 Mar 14 21:57 test.tex
```

When I run `xelatex test`, I get the following error:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)))))kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid fontname `[/home/richard/HelveticaNeueLTPro-Roman.otf]/OT', contains '['

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "HelveticaNeueLTPro-Roman" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.9   Extension = .otf]
```

So far as I can see, I've done exactly what is described in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/385459/16883).  I've also tried putting the path in braces per [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/244471), though I think that's only necessary if you spaces or other special characters in the path.  I've also tried using the old `\setmainfont` syntax per [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/233935), though my `fontspec` package seems to be from 2017 (the TexLive packages are the Debian ones labelled `2016.20170123-5`).  I've also tried using `xltxtra` instead of `fontspec` per [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/482).  I've tried removing the `Extension = .otf` and appending `.otf` to each font name.  I've tried removing the `Path` parameter as it's in the local directors.  I've tried just putting a bare `\setmainfont{HelveticaNeueLTPro-Roman.otf}`.  None of these change the error I see.

Any suggestions?  One thing I can't do is install the fonts as root.

Comment: A suggestion is to try it on overleaf to see if it compiles there (https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/XeLaTeX)  ... (Also the font should be installed on your system as any font or on your projects directory... Not sure if your project is just on your home or on a folder in your home)

Comment: Your font selections also don’t match the actual filenames. For example, `HelveticaNeueLTPro-Bd.otf` should have `BoldFont = *-Bd`.  However, I’m not sure why it’s not parsing the `Extension = .otf` right.

Comment: If you want to install a font only for yourself on Linux, put it in `~/.fonts/`.  This works without root access.  Since you’re using XeTeX, you might re-run `fc-cache`.

Comment: @Davislor - Thanks.  You're right, I got the bold, italics, and bold italics font names wrong.  I've corrected them above, but it makes no difference.  I guess that's unsurprising as it's the regular font it's trying and failing to load.

Comment: @Davislor - I've just tried putting them in `~/.fonts/` and running `fc-cache`.  It still fails in the same way.  I've tried with and without a `Path` parameter.

Comment: I don’t have that specific font to test, but make sure you’re running an up-to-date installation?

Comment: Does `fc-list | grep HelveticaNeue` find them?

Comment: The error seems to be that it’s adding a spurious set of `[]` around the filename.  I’m not sure why, but make sure you’re running the current version of `fontspec`.

Comment: Another workaround might be to install in `~/.fonts`, `fc-cache`, get the family name with `otfinfo` and load that, e.g. `\setmainfont{Helvetica Neue LT Pro}[Scale = 1.0]` or whatever it is.

Comment: @Davislor - no, `fc-list` doesn't list them.  It's a fairly up-to-date installation: Debian "stretch" with TexLive packages that seem to be from 2016-17. I can't see a version number in `fontspec.sty` but the copyright statement is 2017, so it's fairly up to date.  Nevertheless, I do wonder whether this font has some bleeding-edge functionality that isn't supported.

Comment: Well, if you can’t install a new font, you also can’t install a new TeX Live. Another possible workaround: create `HelveticaNeue.fontspec` with `BoldFont = HelveticaNeueLTPro-Bd.otf`, etc.

Comment: You might need to add brackets, i.e., `BoldFont = [HelveticaNeueLTPro-Bd.otf]`.

Comment: `otfinfo` fails with an assertion failure.  I think this tells me the `.odf` file is either corrupt or contains some unsupported functionality: probably the latter as it works fine in Adobe InDesign.  Sounds like I should find a newer installation to test it on, or give up with that particular font.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like some kind of bug in your installation. You could try again on Overleaf, following  the suggestion of @koleygr.